# Indentar todo código automaticamente no vim

Tags: vim, indentação

É possível fazer com que o vim indente automaticamente um arquivo inteiro?

Por exemplo, no Eclipse é possível utilizar o atalho Ctrl+A + Ctrl+I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para indentar um arquivo inteiro no vim, basta digitar o comando `gg=G`.

Porém, este comando faz com que a posição do cursor mude para a primeira linha do código.

Para evitar isso, utilize o comando `gg=G''` ou ``` gg=G`` ```. O primeiro volta para a mesma linha que o usuário estava ao executar o comando, e o segundo volta para a mesma posição (mesma linha e mesma coluna).

Porém, este comando faz com que a posição da tela mude.

Para evitar isso, utilize o comando `` mqHmwgg=G`wzt`q ``. Note que este comando grava uma macro no marcador `w`. Como o comando é muito grande, recomendo criar um atalho para ele. Por exemplo: `` map <D-i> mqHmwgg=G`wzt`q ``.

*Obs: resposta inspirada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086402/indenting-entire-file-in-vim-without-leaving-current-cursor-location) do Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 0):

Para esta operação é possível criar um atalho. A seguir é mostrado como criar um atalho com F7:

```
map <F7> mzgg=G`z
```